# ASP.NET Login Problem

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

I have created a WebSite in ASP.Net(Not Mvc. i forgot the other name).

After finishing the web. I am clicking on the "Build" button, trying to register to the website on a normal asp.net register form, and i am geting this error:

> An error occurred during the execution
>   of the SQL file 'InstallCommon.sql'.
>   The SQL error number is 5123 and the
>   SqlException message is: CREATE FILE
>   encountered operating system error
>   5(failed to retrieve text for this
>   error. Reason: 15105) while attempting
>   to open or create the physical file
>   'C:\INETPUB\WWWROOT\ALON\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB_TMP.MDF'.
>   CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file
>   names listed could not be created.
>   Check related errors. Creating the
>   ASPNETDB_0e95afe2ec5d4f3d93bb9e61527a5bcf
>   database...

I am using IIS7.5 on windows 7. Visual Stuido 2010 Pro.

Any one have idea on how to solve this problem?

Comment: Sounds like ASPNETDB_TMP.MDF is locked by some other process.  Are you sure you don't have another solution open using it?  Have you restarted VS, your computer?

Comment: i have closed all the visual stuiods form that was opend, reseted the is 7.5 and still its not working, i didnt reset the computer.. but i dont thnik its has any affect.

Comment: it might be a security issue. Maybe the account under which your web application is running does not have the permission to create a DB in the SQL Server Express instance.

Comment: i am not sure i am useing SQL Server Express, i am useing an windows sql server 2008, does it metter?

Comment: @Alon from the error message you've posted, it seems that the creation of the database is being attempted in App_Data _("C:\INETPUB\WWWROOT\ALON\APP_DATA\")_ , that's why I think it's Sql Express. However the same thing applies to Sql server 2008: the user that your application pool is running as should have the permission to create a db in the SQL instance you're using. Try changing the user in the app pool temporarily to an administrator (assuming you're on your development machine and not in production)

Comment: @Alon glad I've been of help. I'll copy my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you're using a standard login form along with the Membership API. When using SQL Server Express Edition in conjunction with ASP.NET, the SqlMembershipProvider is able to create a data store that will be used by your membership provider automatically for you. However, when using any other edition of SQL Server, you have to create this data storage manually.

You can use the aspnet_regsql.exe tool and then configure your connection strings.

Hope this [tutorial](http://www.asp.net/security/tutorials/creating-the-membership-schema-in-sql-server-cs) will help.

Answer (score 0):

The user that your application pool is running as should have the permission to create a db in the SQL instance you're using. Try changing the user in the app pool temporarily to an administrator (assuming you're on your development machine and not in production).